# Cancellation postback discontinued from Google Wallet For Digital Goods

Tags: payment, android-pay

Does anyone know why Google Wallet for Digital Goods doesn't send postback requests to the server when subscription was cancelled? 
Is there some delay or this is a bug? 
I didn't saw nothing about delays. And some time ago cancellation pastback come to my server in a few seconds. Today I see that no cancellation pastback for the several hours.

When I make payment, my server gets postback requests for new payments, unfortunately server receives nothing when I cancel my subscription in Google Wallet console (either Merchant Center or Buyer Center).

This behavior is observed in real and sandbox accounts.

I've added logging of income requests before any actions to exclude possible bugs in my code, so I can be sure that no requests from Google Wallet go to my server.

Comment: As far as I remember, only cancellations by a _BUYER_ generate a `failure postback` (not if the _Merchant_ cancels). I currently have issues with my Merchant Center :), so if you can give your sandbox page URL, I can buy a subscription and cancel for you to test. Hth...

Comment: `only cancellations by a BUYER generate` - that is not truth because when we migrate from Checkout we did a system that helps us to manage subscriptions but we manually cancel "re-created" subscriptions in merchant center and our server received cancellation postback. Now our server doesn't know about cancelled subscriptions.

Comment: Just checked the logs... one cancellation notification was received by our server. Cancellation was tomorrow.

Comment: That was only one notification. But Google Wallet does not notify our server about new cancellations.

Comment: It was busted for some time but it is working again. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20575328/304683)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** After contacting Google again and having our request escalated we've been told; "We are investigating the issue with past cancellation notifications. Currently it appears that subscription cancellation notifications are correctly sent"

We've also found that new cancellations are now coming through correctly.

It's still not clear what went wrong or if the system was deliberately taken offline and put back on, however full service seems to be restored. Previously missing postbacks have not been sent through at this time.

---

We've been having similar issues with cancellations not going through over the past week. I've contacted Google and just received this response;

"I've gathered the advice of our specialists. They have confirmed that we are no longer sending notifications for cancelled orders."

This would be affected to our decision to use Google Wallet -  we definitely would not have chosen to use it if we knew the feature was not going to be supported. If you're affected I suggest contacting them to tell them it's important to you. You can do so here: https://support.google.com/payments/?hl=en#contact=1

Comment: I hope this is not the case. The cancellation callbacks are the only way to sync the subscription state with our database.
The notifications are still part of the api as state here:

https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/digital/docs/subscriptions#6


They won't break the workflow of a running PAYMENT system without any prior notice to all merchants to migrate to a different solution.

Comment: Subscription Cancellation postback is working now! See  EdSF's last comment for question. I've checked it and works.