# Google Wallet digital goods: No subscription cancelled callback

Tags: android-pay

I've been using Google Wallet for handling our subscriptions for some months now.
Everything seemed to work fine but I just found out that Google Wallet does not send subscription cancel confirmations any more when a user cancels the subscription.
I still receive subscription success callbacks, but our server simply does not get any subscription cancel events.
Now I have a bunch of active subscriptions on our end that are already cancelled in Google Wallet.
As there is no way to query the subscription state I am totally lost.
Is this is general or a temporary problem or has the wallet API been changed?

Answer (score 1):

It *was* broken (at least in *sandbox* for me), but is now working again. You should get a `SUBSCRIPTON_CANCELED` failure postback if/when a user cancels his/her subscription.

My Sandbox buyer (I cancelled a subscription as a buyer) and got an email:
[image: Buyer email subscription cancellation]

Here's the failure postback for it (sandbox ):
[image: Postback from Google]

Answer (score 0):

No, there is currently no way to find out if a subscription has been cancelled without manually looking at each order. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20556528/123444