# Google Wallet - how to list subscriptions?

Tags: android-pay

As I'm not gettting cancellation events from Google Wallet I need to verify the subscription state manually and update our database one by one.

How can I see the active/cancelled subscriptions in the merchant center?

I'm getting customer requests regarding cancelled subscriptions but I don't find the subscriptions in the merchant center. Please help!

Comment: Yup there are Merchant Center issues...though cancellation postbacks seem to be [working again](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20575328/304683) (sandbox for me)